# Mac OS X El Capitan, Option key alone as keyboard shortcut

Tags: mac, macos, shortcut, input-source

I am using Macbook Air Mid2012 with El Captian 10.11.3 version.

I have two languages installed (two input sources). Currently my shortcut to toggle the language input is "CMD + space." I would like to use the option key on the right-hand-side as a shortcut for input source toggle.

System Preferences - Keyboard - Shortcuts - Input sources won't allow me to specify option key alone as a valid shortcut.

Is there anyway to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

It seems that modifier keys like <kbd>cmd</kbd>, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>, <kbd>option</kbd>, <kbd>shift</kbd> cannot be used alone and have to be combined with other keys as shortcuts. Alternatively you may also try using <kbd>option</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd> as the shortcut to toggle input sources.